# Is there a way to run a local bash function in ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've got a script that needs to run a whole bunch of commands on a remote server. I was wondering if there was to call a local bash function during an ssh session. My current code triggers a `command not found` response, which presumably means that it's running the function as a Unix comand on the remote server, is there a way to make it expand the function?

```sh
ssh host.domain << EOF
    runMemberSetup 1
EOF
```

Since I realize the obvious answer is to do away with the function and paste its contents in the here document, I suppose it would be worth mentioning that there are a lot of these `ssh` calls on various servers, so it would just look ugly and be rather massive if I had to paste the function's contents into each here document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should copy the script or install binary file "runMemberSetup" to the remote host. And if it's runnable in the remote server from the remote server itself, then you can run it through ssh locally.

Comment: This is eventually what I had to end up doing